# Apache Camel Shared Transaction Resource

Tags: spring, hibernate, activemq-classic, apache-camel, spring-transactions

I have a Spring-Camel app backed with a Mysql+Hibernate on a Tomcat. I'm trying to implement a [transacted route](http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html) that consumes from embedded ActiveMQ queue, makes some db based duplicate check and produces to another embedded ActiveMQ queue.

To provide transactionality I'm using [Shared Transaction Resource pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-spring-transactions.html?page=4). Both Hibernate sessionFactory and ActiveMQ BrokerService JDBCPersistenceAdapter use the same datasource.

Camel endpoints use HibernateTransactionManager(PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW). It seems to be working but I want to clarify if this is a bulletproof approach in case of system crash, failure,

Do I need to migrate to jta, 2PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going on with XA (Atomikos)

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful if you were to provide the rationale behind this decision. E.g. benefits of XA over other products.

Comment: Performance is poor for JDBCPersistenceAdapter. Move on to standalone storage for ActiveMQ (KahaDB). For that scenario xa is the only way to provide transactionality. Using no jee container, so atomikos seems to be the only way.